# Bash CSV sorting and unique-ing

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, awk, unique

a Linux question: I have the CSV file `data.csv` with the following fields and values

```
KEY,LEVEL,DATA
2.456,2,aaa
2.456,1,zzz
0.867,2,bbb
9.775,4,ddd
0.867,1,ccc
2.456,0,ttt 
...
```

The field `KEY` is a float value, while `LEVEL` is an integer. I know that the first field can have repeated values, as well as the second one, but if you take them together you have a unique couple.

What I would like to do is to sort the file according to the column `KEY` and then for each unique value under `KEY` keep only the row having the higher value under `LEVEL`.
Sorting is not a problem:

```
$> sort -t, -k1,2 data.csv  # fields: KEY,LEVEL,DATA
0.867,1,ccc
0.867,2,bbb
2.456,0,ttt
2.456,1,zzz
2.456,2,aaa
9.775,4,ddd
...
```

but then how can I filter the rows so that I get what I want, which is:

```
0.867,2,bbb
2.456,2,aaa
9.775,4,ddd
...
```

Is there a way to do it using command line tools like `sort`, `uniq`, `awk` and so on? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this line:

```
your sort...|awk -F, 'k&&k!=$1{print p}{p=$0;k=$1}END{print p}'
```

output:

```
kent$  echo "0.867,1,bbb
0.867,2,ccc
2.456,0,ttt
2.456,1,zzz
2.456,2,aaa
9.775,4,ddd"|awk -F, 'k&&k!=$1{print p}{p=$0;k=$1}END{print p}'
0.867,2,ccc
2.456,2,aaa
9.775,4,ddd
```

The idea is, because your file is already sorted, just go through the file/input from top, if the first column (`KEY`) changed, print the last line, which is the highest value of `LEVEL` of last `KEY`

try with your real data, it should work.

also the whole logic (with your sort) could be done by awk in single process.

Comment: OK this worked out perfectly - and thanks for the explanation (so next time I can remember how to do), thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
$> sort -r data.csv | uniq -w 5 | sort
```

given your floats are formatted "0.000"-"9.999"

Answer (score 0):

Perl solution:

```
perl -aF, -ne '$h{$F[0]} = [@F[1,2]] if $F[1] > $h{$F[0]}[0]
               }{
               print join ",", $_, @{$h{$_}} for sort {$a<=>$b} keys %h' data.csv
```

Note that the result is different from the one you requested, the first line contains `bbb`, not `ccc`.